# Printing the HorizontalScrollView within NestedScrollView on Android

Tags: java, android, horizontal-scrolling, android-nestedscrollview

I have a NestedScrollView and within this I have a HorizontalScrollView. I need to take print of the entire screen.Could someone please guide me on how to do this?

I have followed the answer provided by @ZeroOne [Take whole "Screenshot" of a scrollable View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44129322/take-whole-screenshot-of-a-scrollable-view). It captures the complete vertical scroll part but horizontally only the part that is visible on the screen at that moment. How do I print the whole view or is it even possible?

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cardTitle"
                style="@style/SetTextRowHeader"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_large"
                android:text="Counts" />

            .
            .

      <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_large"
        android:scrollbars="none">
            .

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cardTitle"
                style="@style/SetTextRowHeader"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_large"
                android:text="Counts" />
                .
                .
                .
      </HorizontalScrollView>
  </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: you can find your answer from below link. Hope it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234371/capture-screenshot-of-a-horizontalscrollview-including-offscreen-elements

Comment: @NensiKasundra It's not working